# Comparing integer Arrays in Java. Why does not == work?

Tags: java, comparison, compare

I'm learning Java and just came up with this subtle fact about the language: if I declare two integer Arrays with the same elements and compare them using `==` the result is `false`. Why does this happen? Should not the comparison evaluate to `true`?

```
public class Why {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3};

        System.out.println(a == b);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, because `==` compares references, not values.

Comment: Others have answered the question, but I'll add that this is a very important thing to understand in Java, or any language that has objects or structs as references.  As written, you are creating two separate objects that happen to have the same numbers in them.  If you had written "int[] b = a;" then b would be pointing to the same memory as a, and then a==b would be true.

Comment: @jfrank That's a bit too generic. C# and python for example do have objects as references but `==` will still give the right result (well for python at least, c# has its own downfalls there).

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that == behaved the same in each language with references, so my bad if that's how it came out. I meant to emphasize the importance of understanding the notions of references and memory, in order to program successfully in those languages.  IMHO there is no "right" behavior for the == operator, since equality is a nuanced concept when you have references.  If you don't understand references, you have no chance to understand the different kinds of equality properly.

Answer (score 35):

Use [**Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)) method.

The `==` *operator* just checks if two references point to the same object.

**Test:**

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = a;    
System.out.println(a == b);   // returns true as b and a refer to the same array  

int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a, b));   //returns true as a and b are meaningfully equal
```

Comment: Howto find difrerences without using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

No. `==`compares numerical (or boolean) values, or references, only.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21

You're probably looking for the `Arrays.equals (a,b)` method

Answer (score 0):

If you use `==` operator with `Object` you are comparing the **references**, not the **values**.
If you use `==` operator with primitive types (`int`, `long`, `boolean`...) you are checking if they have the same values.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = {1, 2, 3};

System.out.println(a == b); //return false;

System.out.println(a[0] == b[0]); //return true;



String[] a1 = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"};
String[] b2 = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"};

System.out.println(a1 == b1); //return false;

System.out.println(a1[0] == b1[0]); //return false; Because String are Object
```

You can use the **`Arrays.equals(array1, array2)`** method.