# Converting bitmap to byte array, to string, then all the way back

Tags: java, android, string, bitmap, arrays

I have tried several different methods found in the java documentation, as well as several solutions from other SO questions and have successfully gotten a `Bitmap` to convert to a `byte[]` and back again.

The problem is that I now need to convert this byte[] to a `String`, then back to a `byte[]`, then back to a `Bitmap` again.  To recap what I need:

`Bitmap -> byte[] -> String -> byte[] -> Bitmap`

I know this sounds strange but what I'm trying to accomplish *must* be done this way.  Below is what I have tried, if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
Bitmap bitmap = mv.getDrawingCache();

// Convert bitmap to byte[]
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
byte[] imageBytes = output.toByteArray();

// Convert byte[] to string
// I have also tried using Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, 0);

String encodedString = new String(imageBytes);

// Convert string to byte[]
byte[] newImageBytes = encodedString.getBytes();

if (imageBytes == newImageBytes) {
    Toast.makeText(SignatureActivity.this, "SUCCESS!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else { // Sadly, we always get to this point :(
    Toast.makeText(SignatureActivity.this, "BOOO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// Convert byte[] back to bitmap
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(newImageBytes, 0, newImageBytes.length);
```

Again, going `Bitmap -> byte[] -> Bitmap` was successful, but adding in the conversion to a `String` and back is causing the final `Bitmap` to write an image of 0kb.

Comment: Does it matter what the string contains as long as it represents the Bitmap?

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as I can eventually retrieve the original bitmap from it

Comment: Perhaps the default character encoding on Android is always UTF-8, but you should typically avoid using the default character encoding. I would explicitly use UTF-8 in both the String ctor and the call to getBytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the conversion, but how you verify the result. using `==` to compare two arrays only returns true if they are the same array reference. Since you create a new array with `byte[] newImageBytes = encodedString.getBytes();` This will always be false. 
[See this question for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614928/comparing-integer-arrays-in-java-why-does-not-work)

On another note, if you are going to transfer or use the string in some way, it is probably better to use `Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);` to get a string, and get it back with [`Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.NO_WRAP)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).
You can also get the byte array without compressing it, with the [`copyPixelsToBuffer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29) method (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191871/converting-bitmap-to-bytearray-android) for an example).

Comment: I should add that prior to this, i was using `.equals()` to compare the byte arrays, but it also didn't work :(  I'll change back and try your suggestions though!

Comment: @RhinoFeeder note that the answer to the refered question uses `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)`, and not `.equals(a2)`