# Write Bitmap to a MIME message

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64, mime

Edit 2 : from the result I got in my first edit, at the bottom of the post, the issue is somewhere at this line or below : `imageEncodedSigneAgent = Base64.encodeToString(byteSigneAgent,Base64.NO_WRAP);` "
/edit.

I tried to write a bitmap in a MIME message, as a Base64 String in PNG format. Sadly, the message is considered as null (windows viewer can't read it, says size is 0kb)

My code :

```
        Bitmap bitmapSigne = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileSigne.getAbsolutePath());
        if (Params.tagFgDebug && fgDebugLocal){Log.i(Params.tagGen, tagLocal + "createEMLInt - bitmapSigne width = " + bitmapSigne.getWidth());};
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmapSigne.getByteCount());  
        if (!bitmapSigne.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)) {
            new TException(tagLocal, "Compress bitmapSign == ", "false");
        }
        byte[] byteSigne = baos.toByteArray(); 
        if (Params.tagFgDebug && fgDebugLocal){Log.i(Params.tagGen, tagLocal + "createEMLInt - byteSigne size = " + byteSigne.length);};
        String imageEncodedSigne = Base64.encodeToString(byteSigne,Base64.NO_WRAP);
        if (Params.tagFgDebug && fgDebugLocal){Log.i(Params.tagGen, tagLocal + "createEMLInt - imageEncodedSigne size = " + imageEncodedSigne.length());};
        mime.append(imageEncodedSigne);
        mime.append("\r\n");
```

This does write base64 lines in my MIMI message, but it can't be read and is a bit short maybe. I think it might be metadata around the PNG (from what I read after I decode it).

I tested to save the bitmap directly to a File and it works perfectly :

```
        // test to retrieve BitMap as PNG
        String signePath2 = Baseline.strSdExternalPath + File.separator + Params.MIF_REP;
        File file = new File(signePath2, "sign.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmapSigne.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        // test to retrieve BitMap as PNG
```

I correctly get the image I draw previously.

I also tried (idea from another SO question : [Converting bitmap to byte array, to string, then all the way back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621285/converting-bitmap-to-byte-array-to-string-then-all-the-way-back)) to reconvert the String to a bitmap and it fails :(

```
            byte[] newImageBytes = imageEncodedSigne.getBytes();
        // Convert byte[] back to bitmap
        Bitmap bitmapReconverted = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(newImageBytes, 0, newImageBytes.length);
        File fileReconverted = new File(signePath2, "signReConverted.png");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileReconverted);
        bitmapReconverted.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
```

What am I missing here ? Why do I fail to properly retrieve the byte data and get a readable string in base64 ?

Any help appreciate !

I used Base64.DEFAULT before to no better results. I read several post and the one linked is the closest to what I am trying to do, sadly his issue was with a bad use of 'equalTo'

EDIT  : So I tried to do Bitmap -> bytes[] -> Bitmap and it worked :

```
Bitmap bitmapReconverted = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteSigne, 0, byteSigne.length);
        File fileReconverted = new File(signePath2, "signReConverted.png");
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileReconverted);
        bitmapReconverted.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
```

Edit 3 : the MIME result for documentation purpose !

```
Content-Type: image/png
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body";filename="20150601.190623_00008_SIGN.PNG" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAABuCAIAAAC86/hZAAAA

Comment: side note: `new TException(...)` apparently does not do anything. You possibly mean `throw new TException(...)`

Comment: Yes, yes it does. You can't know it but it is a custom Exception wrapper, maybe it's bad design to not have the ''throw'' method called there.

Comment: it's possibly not a very good design. It is not clear from the code posted, but it could be that the creation of the object is not useful. Also, creating a subclass of exception helps with catching it. And the `throw` keyword instantly explains what is going on.

Comment: can you post your log?

Comment: Hi, I could post the MIME message if you think that would help you. The exception is not thrown. Check my Edits, the issue is not there, it is somewhere below in the code.

Comment: Another point is that you apparently load the image from a file, then put it in a byte[] as a png, then... You could load the file directly in the byte[], that would save some cpu time, and possibly avoid compression issues.

Comment: Ok,  I just checked that I can totally opened it if I take just the string, decode it and save it as a png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct except this part :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body";filename="20150601.190623_00008_SIGN.PNG" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAABuCAIAAAC86/hZAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAZsEl
```

That should be written like this :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body";filename="20150601.190623_00008_SIGN.PNG" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOYAAABuCAIAAAC86/hZAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAZsEl
```

Notice the additional line ? Yup, that's all folks.