# Java - I'm getting wrong output from equals method

Tags: java

Here I'm trying to test if my objects are equals!
Regarding this arrays the output should be:
True
False
False

But I'm getting this output:
False
False
False

Why the first equality is False?

```
//arrays
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {1, 2, 3}  
c = {2, 3, 1} 

static void testEquals(Scanner scanner) {
    int[] a = readArray(scanner);
    int[] b = readArray(scanner);
    int[] c = readArray(scanner);
    IntegerArray ia = new IntegerArray(a);
    IntegerArray ib = new IntegerArray(b);
    IntegerArray ic = new IntegerArray(c);
    System.out.println(ia.equals(ib));
    System.out.println(ia.equals(ic));
    System.out.println(ib.equals(ic));
}
```

Here is the implementation of the IntegerArray class:
*Note: This class must be immutable

```
final class IntegerArray {
private int[] a;

public IntegerArray(int arr[]) {
    a = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = arr[i];
    }
}

public int length() {
    return a.length;
}

public int getElementAt(int i) {
    return a[i];
}

public int sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public double average() {
    return (double) this.sum() / this.length();
}

public IntegerArray getSorted() {
    int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    Arrays.sort(temp);
    return new IntegerArray(temp) ;
}
}
```

Comment: Please show your `IntegerArray` class.  You probably haven't overridden `equals`.

Comment: your assumption is incorrect. Equals method check for object references in this case.

Comment: Yes, ia and ib are two different objects, whose members happen to be equal. But they are different objects

Comment: @RamPrakash We can't know that until we see the implementation of `IntegerArray`.  It's possible that the the OP *did* override `equals()`, but has an error in their implementation.

Comment: @azurefrog i agree with you

Comment: @rgettman You can check now my IntegerArray class! 
Yes I haven't overridden equals becausw I don't know how to do that propperly, I'm a beginner with Java!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `IntegerArray` class from [Xalan for Java](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/xsltc/util/IntegerArray.html#IntegerArray(int[])), the problem is that the class does not provide an override for `equals()` and `hashCode()`. That is why the default `Object` comparison is used, which compares references to `IntegerArray` objects.

Unfortunately, you cannot derive from Xalan's `IntegerArray` class, because it is `final`. You can write your own wrapper, or compare `int[]` arrays directly, as explained in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14614948/335858).

Answer (score 1):

------FIXED------
Thank you everyone for your time and help!!
I fixed my program by overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    IntegerArray that = (IntegerArray) o;

    return Arrays.equals(a, that.a);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per Java 8,the wrapper class objects values should never be equal to primitive type values.As a is our primitive array and ia is a wrapper class array.so both stored at different locations in heap and stack respectively.For better understanding you can go through this code and run it on the java ide you.

[the image shows you the difference in the values of both the two arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2oCj.png)